# What's with all the language switcher module questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, user-accounts

There have been 3 of basically the same questions regarding Joomla's language switcher module.
Each question is being asked by a different user, however is it the same person?

Can the IP addresses be checked to confirm?

Here are the questions:

- [Question 1](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/create-custom-language-switcher-module)
- [Question 2](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5405/joomla-language-switcher-layout)
- [Question 3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/hide-languages-from-the-joomla-language-switcher)

Comment: Can you add the links to the questions please? I will look into it.

Comment: @Valentin Despa - My bad. Update above with the question links

Comment: 3 different countries. But you can mark them as duplicate.